# SharePoint 2010 - Generate reports from SharePoint Database?

Tags: sql-server, reports, sql

It is possible to generate reports from the SharePoint Database with informations like current users, teamsites, websites etc. ?
I heard maybe it is possible with the WSS-Logging Database.

Are there any examples? Experience with generating reports like this? Other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell is going to be your best bet.  Interacting directly with the database is not encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

there are commercial vendors (Avepoint, Idera, Quest, et al) that offer reporting utilities that read the SP databases.. 
you may want to consider using the Usage & Health Data services to obtain similar information (see - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663480.aspx ).

Comment: found a nice blog post regarding Web Analytics Reporting (as per John Chapman's post above) -
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Under Site Actions > Site Settings there are some analytics at the site collection and site levels.

For Farm Level analytics, goto Central Admin and under Monitoring goto View Web Analytics.

For more farm-level reports (i.e. structure, sites, etc.) we use SPDocKit.